# Multiple timers with different intervals, writing to the same target

Tags: c#, .net, service, timer, system.timers.timer

I'm writing a Windows Service that will execute different data import logic, from different data source to eventually write it to a single target, a MS CRM instance. Right now, the only thing I think will be problematic, is the writing to CRM part. The concurent reading of data from different (sometimes same) data source shouldn't really be an issue (I may be wrong on this...) So I came up with a way to make sure there are no concurent writes (create or updates) to CRM.

Here's the general design for the moment:

What happens when the service starts:

```
Timers = new List<System.Timers.Timer>();
CrmTransactionQueue.Lock = new object { }; //Static class. The object for locking purposes...
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000); //for debugging purpose so I can attach to process before everything kicks in...

//retrieve all types that are extending BaseSyncStrategy..
var strategyTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(x => x.BaseType == typeof(BaseSyncStrategy));


foreach (Type strategyType in strategyTypes)
{
    //create a instance of that type....
    var strategy = (BaseSyncStrategy)Activator.CreateInstance(strategyType);

    //create a timer for each of these, they will have different intervals...
    System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer
    {
        Interval = strategy.Interval * 1000,
        AutoReset = false,
        Enabled = true
     };

     Timers.Add(t);

     t.Elapsed += (sender, e) => TimerElapsed(sender, e, strategy);
     t.Start();
 }
```

What happens when the timers' interval are expired:

```
private void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e, BaseSyncStrategy strategy)
{
    //get timer back
    var timer = (Timer)sender;

    try
    {
        strategy.Execute();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.WriteEntry(EventLogEntryType.Error, $"Error executing strategy {strategy.GetType().Name}: ", ex);
    }

    timer.Start();
}
```

And within all the `Execute` methods of objects extending `BaseSyncStrategy`, each time I want to update or create something in the target CRM instance, I do this:

```
XrmServiceContext XrmCtx = new XrmServiceContext();

//....
//code that fetches data from foreign sources and creates CRM entities...
//....

Action<XrmServiceContext> action = (XrmServiceContext ctx) =>
{
    //write those created/updated objects
    //ctx lets me query entities and write back to CRM...
};

CrmTransactionQueue.Execute(action, XrmCtx);
```

And the simple code to make sure (I think) no concurent writes to CRM happen:

```
public static class CrmTransactionQueue
{
    public static object Lock { get; set; }

    public static void Execute(Action<XrmServiceContext> transaction, XrmServiceContext Ctx)
    {
        lock (Lock)
        {
            transaction.Invoke(Ctx);
        }
    }

}
```

Is this sound design or there's a better way to do this ?

Comment: And CRM itself cannot handle concurrent inserts and updates?

Comment: @Evk I've had "Generic SQL Errors" doing so in the past. Thing is eventually, I'll add more strategies (extending BaseSyncStratgy) to the service and the same CRM entity may get updated by two or more strategies, so I would think "queuing" is important here.

Comment: Are you sure a service is what you want? What applications will consume the service? Are you sure you don't really want a scheduled task? I'm only asking since you said this was designed to perform an import, something that could certainly be done based on a schedule and configuration rather than as a service.

Check this out: https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/428303

Comment: Not positive but should't this be moved to code review since it is asking about code that already works?

Comment: @Jacobr365 The code posted here is not reviewable in this form because it leaves us guessing at the author's intentions. Unlike Stack Overflow, Code Review needs to look at concrete code in a real context. Please see [Why is hypothetical example code off-topic for CR?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1709/41243)

Comment: But one entity still can be updated by strategy A and then immediatly by strategy B, overwriting changes made by A. Is that ok?

Comment: @Evk I doubt the strategies will negate each other, but if there's a reason for it to happen I don't think that would be a problem.